# How to show deleteConfirmationButton on a clicked UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to make an `UITableViewCell` that shows the deleteConfirmationButton (while in edit mode) just like happens when I click at the editing controls but in my case I want it when the user clicks over the UITableCell.

I've already set the property `AllowsSelectionDuringEditing` to YES and I can delete the rows, I just want the deleteConfirmationButton to avoid any accident.

Any tips on how to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you would probably use the commitEditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath function, which is called when an object is selected or deleted during editing.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
return YES;
 }
```

And then for the confirmation do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
 forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
//make a UIAlert and display confirmation, if yes then run the following code, if no then break

// remove the object
 [myItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// refresh the table view to display your new data
 [tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: That's not what I was looking for but I think it should solve the problem.